# Why wont my python thread react to global variables

Tags: python, variables, global, multiprocess

This code is to start and stop multiple copies of various different thread types. I will preface this with saying I tried using pipes to control the threads but keep getting random memory errors to do with the pipes. This is a prototype of a factory to produce several copies of multiple thread types, so a queue method didn't seem practical to me either though if there is something I am missing I am all ears. So my newest plan is to use a global dictionary with a different entry for every thread and thread kill condition. ie `sub[Alive]` `subKill["kill"]`

Yet for some reason the `control_listener` thread spawned by the processes wont trigger the kill condition and wont read the global variable.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time


alive = {'subAlive': True, 'subKill': "Alive", 'testAlive': True, 'testKill': "Alive"};


def control_listener(aliveFlag, threadAlive): #listens for kill from main
    global alive
    while True:
          data = alive[aliveFlag];
          print "Thread", alive[threadAlive];
          print "Thread status", alive[aliveFlag];
          if data == "kill":
             print "Killing"
             alive[threadAlive] = False; #value for kill
             print "testListner alive %s" % threadAlive, alive[threadAlive];
             print "deactivating %s" % threadAlive, alive['aliveFlag'];
             break

def subprocess(aliveFlag, threadNum, threadAlive):
    t = Thread(target=control_listener, args=(aliveFlag, threadAlive))
    count = 0
    threadVal = threadNum 
    t.start()
    run = alive['subAlive'];
    while run == True:
          print "Thread alive %s" % alive['aliveFlag'];
          print "Thread %d Run number = %d" % (threadVal, count), alive['subAlive'];
          count = count + 1
          run = alive['subAlive']; 


def testprocess(aliveFlag, threadNum, threadAlive):
    t = Thread(target=control_listener, args=(aliveFlag, threadAlive))
    count = 0
    threadVal = threadNum 
    t.start()
    run = alive['testAlive'];
    while run == True:
          print "This is a different thread %d Run = %d" % (threadVal, count)
          count = count + 1
          run = alive['testAlive'];


runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))


print "Starting threads"

for i in range(threadNum):
    p = Process(target=subprocess, args=('subKill', i, 'subAlive'))
    p.start()

print "Subprocess started"

for i in range(threadNum): 
    p2 = Process(target=testprocess, args=('subKill', i, 'testAlive'))
    p2.start()

print "Testproccess started"

print "Starting run"

time.sleep(runNum) 

print "Terminating Subprocess run"
for i in range(threadNum):
    alive['subKill'] = "kill"; 
    print "Subkill = %s" % alive['subKill'];
    print "Testprocess termination alive", alive['subAlive'];

print "Terminating Testprocess run"
for i in range(threadNum):
    alive['subKill'] = "kill"; 
    print "Testprocess termination alive", alive['subAlive'];

p.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: Show us the simplest piece of code that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: You do realize that using `Process` you are creating a new process that *doesn't share* the address space of the original process? I really don't see why you'd expect your code to work. Each process has its own, private `alive` etc. global variables and hence it cannot tell to somebody else to stop.
If you want to share objects among processes use [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to create them into a shared address space.

Comment: Ok, I am redesigning it to take that into account. Thanks!